# Font size with XMing X11 forwarding too small

Tags: ssh, fonts, putty, x11-forwarding, xming

I am using a GUI application running on a remote Linux host, but displaying on my Windows desktop using the XMing server, PuTTY with X11 forwarding, (and `ssh -X` as well, which is done by SLURM's `srun` with `--pty` option).

But the default font is a bit too small. How to increase it?

---

It took me a while to find the answer, so I'm adding it here for anyone else doing the same search.

Answer (score 15):

As suggested [here](http://aufather.wordpress.com/2010/11/21/increasing-font-size-in-xming-server/), passing the `-dpi 108` command-line argument to the XMing server usually works (the default is 96).

Comment: This is also a solution for the same problem with xpra. In this case you want  the `--dpi` flag.